# Asp:Menu and Internet Explorer 8 Issue?

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu

I installed Internet Explorer 8 and now the menu items under the top-level menu items are not being shown.  The background is just white.  If I check it it in IE6 or IE7, the menu items show up fine.  Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, and there is a hotfix.  See [Bertrand's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/03/23/asp-menu-fix-for-ie8-problem-available.aspx).